# Message On Screen Even when my app is closed as per image below : (not as a push Notification)

Tags: android, notifications, android-alertdialog

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEBIZ.jpg)

I want to display a certain text inside closed box every 30 minutes with slide in animation as stated in attached image.

Any recommendation how I can implement this?

Comment: No image has been displayed yet

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Sorry ! i cant post image just links... for image view just clicked on (Example Image ) Text at the top .

Comment: @Minzkraut Thank you, but i already tried with    AlertDialog.Builder and Push notification ...and easily i can post the code here but its not what i intend to do so its not related to my point here.. i want something (similar) to Toast with animation .. if you kindly open the image line above (example image) you will get my point clearly...Thank you